# How to update apollo store after making a mutation in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo

I am new in this apollo graphql and I justtry to understand how this update store works as every time when I make a mutation I have to refresh my app to see the changes. In my following example I am adding a card in my wallet. So to see the new card in my app I have to reload the app.

This part is from AddCard.js where I cand only add the card but I can't see it. So soon as I make the mutation and `goBack()` my card is not showing until I reload the app.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
const GET_ME = gql`
  query me {
    me {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const GET_WALLET = gql`
  query getUserWallet($u_id: ID!) {
    getUserWallet(u_id: $u_id) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const CREATE_CARD = gql`
  mutation($wallet_id: ID!, $cardNo: String!, $exp: String!, $cvc: String!, $card: String! $user: ID!) {
    createPayment(wallet_id: $wallet_id, cardNo: $cardNo, exp: $exp, cvc: $cvc, card: $card, user: $user) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const mutationConfig = {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
        createPayment: (wallet_id, cardNo, exp, cvc, card, user) => mutate({
            variables: { wallet_id, cardNo, exp, cvc, card, user }
        }),
    })
}

export default compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(GET_ME, { name: "getMe" }),
    graphql(GET_WALLET, {
        name: "getWallet",
        options: (props) => (
            {
                variables:
                {
                    u_id: props.getMe.me._id
                }
            }
        )
    }),
    graphql(CREATE_CARD, mutationConfig)
)(AddCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apollo's documentation has been updated to use render props rather than the higher order component. If you check out the section on [updating the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#update) it will show you how to do it. It should work similar for your higher order component. You could pass in an update option, which should give you access to the cache. From there, you can write directly to the cache with writeData/writeQuery or you can alter a fragment with writeFragment.

I hope this helps!